# TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I got an error when I tried to use two checkboxs at the same time in Reactjs. And I got this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined
FormContainer.render
src/container/formcontainer.component.js:268
  265 | <label className="form-check-label">
  266 |   <input
  267 |     type="checkbox"
> 268 |     checked={this.state.departRelated.isExternal.has}
      | ^  269 |     onChange={this.onChangeExternal}
  270 |     className="form-check-input"
  271 |   />
```

### Below is my application:

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      newPost: {
        title: "",
        type: "",
        depart: "",
        selectedList: [],
        description: ""
      },
      departRelated: {
 
        isExternal: {
          has: false,
          name: "External"
        },
        isInternal: {
          have: false,
          name: "Internal"
        }
      };
```

---

```
onChangeExternal = () => {
    this.setState(initialState => ({
      departRelated: {
        isExternal: {
          has: !this.state.departRelated.isExternal.has
        }
      }
    }));
  };

  onChangeInternal = () => {
    this.setState(initialState => ({
      departRelated: {
        isInternal: {
          have: !this.state.departRelated.isInternal.have
        }
      }
    }));
  };
```

---

```
return (
<div className="form-check">
          <label className="form-check-label">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.departRelated.isExternal.has}
              onChange={this.onChangeExternal}
              className="form-check-input"
            />
            External
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check">
          <label className="form-check-label">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={this.state.departRelated.isInternal.have}
              onChange={this.onChangeInternal}
              className="form-check-input"
            />
            Internal
          </label>
          {/* <p>this box is {msg}.</p> */}
        </div>
)
```

---

I only show related parts here. I have to keep both has(have) and name in departRelated because I want to store the name (with has(have) value == true) in my database later.
I comment External part, Internal part works and vice versa. But, when I apply both External and Internal parts, it fails.
Anyone knows why???

Comment: Check the property first before proceeding further.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply some checks for object/properties existence like this

```
return (
<div className="form-check">
          <label className="form-check-label">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={(this.state.departRelated && this.state.departRelated.isExternal) ? this.state.departRelated.isExternal.has: false}
              onChange={this.onChangeExternal}
              className="form-check-input"
            />
            External
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-check">
          <label className="form-check-label">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={(this.state.departRelated && this.state.departRelated.isExternal) ? this.state.departRelated.isInternal.have : false}
              onChange={this.onChangeInternal}
              className="form-check-input"
            />
            Internal
          </label>
          {/* <p>this box is {msg}.</p> */}
        </div>
)
```

Comment: I tried your method. It still showed the same error message like before: TypeError: Cannot read property 'has' of undefined.

Comment: It should resolve that error. Did you clear the cache with Ctrl+Shirt+R